# How to create a color plot inside a contour?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm doing a simulation with dynamical systems. Basically for every initial condition (x,y) in the 2D plane I calculate a certain quantity, which is a real number. My objective is to take a bunch of points and calculate the said quantity for each point, then make a color plot.

This particular simulation involves a potential energy function, with x and y as input. I fix the energy and plot a contour of the function (using plt.contour from matplotlib). I would like to create a color plot inside this contour.

So far I've only performed simulations on rectangular domains and used np.meshgrid, but this time I've no idea how to do it. Can anyone offer some suggestions? So far I have this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def V(x,y):
   return 0.5*(x**2+y**2)+(x**2)*y-(1.0/3.0)*(y**3)

def my_function(x,y,h):
   # insert function here
   # returns a real number > 0 

#The following segment plots a contour of V at value h:
def plot_contour(h):
    x=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,200)
    y=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,200)
    X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
    Z=np.zeros((200,200))
    for i in range(200):
        for j in range(200):
            Z[i,j]=V(X[i,j],Y[i,j])
    plt.contour(X,Y,Z,[h])
    plt.show()

#The following segment creates a color plot on a rectangular domain
def color_plot(h):
    x=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,200)
    y=np.linspace(-1.0,1.0,200)
    X,Y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
    Z=np.zeros((200,200))
    for i in range(200):
        for j in range(200):
            Z[i,j]=my_function(X[i,j],Y[i,j],h)
    plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
    plt.show()
```

I'd like to do the following: pick a value of `h`, compute the contour of `V` at `h`, color plot the values of `my_function(x,y,h)` where `(x,y)` is a point **inside** the contour. Hence the color plot is restricted only to points within the contour line. Basically like this

[image: like this]

Comment: This is too broad to know what the actual problem is. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve]; then [edit] your question accordingly. People here are always happy to help but if they need to guess wildly at what point you need help, they will simply ignore your question.

Comment: Thank you, I edited the question and included the code and an example

Comment: Yes, it's much clearer now. You may nominate your question for reopening. The problem is that now you need to wait for 4 other people to vote for it. You may keep that in mind, and spend more effort to ask a clear question from the beginning next time.